# adding an image to react js

Tags: reactjs, image, url

```
<CardMedia
                  className={classes.cardMedia}
                  image="https://source.unsplash.com/random"
                  title="Image title"
                />
```

i have this card component that has an image
this works perfectly but it generates an random image according ti the url "https://source.unsplash.com/random"

i need to replace the url with an other one from a google image
but when i put the link for example (https://www.google.com/search?q=credit+card+images&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=yTCt2mYy4QLi2M%252C-uamK6tjDy_5gM%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kQyjcIQ9sXlfX8yIJxLD3J9BMHRUw&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiO48bludHqAhVI2KQKHXWzCskQ9QEwAXoECAYQMg&biw=1366&bih=657#imgrc=blCwDWRxIOqbxM)

nothing happens and no image shows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the desired image and choose `Copy image address`. That's the address you want to use in your app.